# Short story about a machine that provides people with what they want

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia

There is an old sci fi short story (I think) about a civilization that creates a huge machine to provide all that people want, on demand.  They think "apple", and one materializes in their hand.  Much of the story takes place before the machine is switched on, but when it is switched on, it decides to leave mankind behind and goes off to the stars.  It may have been Philip K Dick - does anyone know the story, and the author?

Edit: I read this story myself over 20 years ago, and even then it was probably about 20 years old.  So we're talking 1950s, 1960s, 1970s era, and probably not later.  The story was mostly around the philosophical aspects of having a machine do everything for you, instead of making the effort yourself.  I think the story took place mostly over a single evening, the few hours before the midnight switch-on.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in anything else you may remember? For example, you say it is old, do you know how old?

Comment: I think I've read every PKD short story, and while it's hard to *remember* all of them, aside from a slight resemblance to "[Autofac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autofac)", this doesn't ring any bells.

Comment: Definitely not Autofac - but thanks!  It may well have been an author other than PKD.